# Score not synced for days

Tags: bug, tag-score

I noted that score on my profile page, when opening on PC, is showing a wrong value, which is several days old, while on mobile app, it shows correctly.

I know scores are not updated realtime, but this has been for days. Is anything wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @NathanTuggy Not a dupe, I knew it is updated daily before I post this, the issue here it has not been updated at least 5 days. However, on mobile app it is updated ok, only on webpage.

Comment: The point is that it's updated daily *unreliably*.

Comment: Ok, then there is still the issue of inconsistence between webpage and mobileapp.

Comment: @Veve Indeed, thank you! closing

Comment: closed as duplicate.